# Name of the low wall at the edge of a loft

Tags: single-word-requests

A loft overlooking the main floor. The loft is not a complete floor so there is an edge that has a low wall maybe one third or one half the height of the room...

I think of 'parapet', 'bulwark' but these seem heavy-handed for an interior wall.

See for example, the wall for the bedroom that overlooks the living room in this image taken by [JP Image](https://www.jp-image.com/) of a Brazilian loft apartment:

[image: view from the living room looking up toward a loft bedroom]

Comment: Do you mean side? edge is confusing here. And is this loft in a vaulted ceiling or not?